# Dark/light matplotlib style according to PyCharm Dark/Light mode

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

In both PyCharm and `matplotlib` you can select Dark or Light mode (e.g. `plt.style.use('dark_background')`). Using `matplotlib` in default light mode while PyCharm in dark mode makes plot ticks unreadable when running `jupyter` (black on dark).
I wonder if one can query the mode of PyCharm (read some settings file?) and enable `matplotlib` dark style conditionally. Or another way around somehow make default `matplotlib` account for PyCharm mode.
Simple workaround is to define environmental variable.

Anyone know the robust solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I run into that issue too. But I noticed saving the figure and viewing the saved picture has the ticks and markings.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('savefig.png')
```

[Pop-up after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju66L.jpg)

[savefile.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raKa3.png)